# Can I utilize AWS Cognito for an Ejabberd server authentication?

Tags: authentication, xmpp, ejabberd, amazon-cognito

Pretty new to the Ejabberd world. I am trying to understand the authentication with ejabberd. 
So I have a mobile chat app where I am registering users via AWS Cognito and now I have to register them to the Ejabberd server aswell.

Now, **is there a way for me to use this Cognito authentication to register/authenticate a user to my ejabberd server?**

Or should the app auth and the ejabberd auth be treated *separately* and I have to first register via Cognito and when that is successful I have to go through ejabberd's auth process and create a user, which has no relation to the cognito user.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way for me to use this Cognito authentication to
>   register/authenticate a user to my ejabberd server?

Yes, you can write an [extauth script](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#external-script) that ejabberd will start, and will query to verify user logins. There is an [example script](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/examples/extauth/check_pass_null.pl) that accepts all logins... but in your case, you want that script to connect to your database, and accept only those accounts+passwords that are registered in your system.

See more example extauth scripts in [Contributions](https://www.ejabberd.im/extauth/index.html).